# How to run my express app on digital ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean and I spent quite some time setting it up by following their tutorials and all that. Then I SFTP'd my app to my server and it got transferred and everything then I ran `sudo npm start` and the console says that it's running but when I visit http://share3na.com as you can see nothing shows up. I installed all of the modules by running `sudo npm install --save [module]` then after manually doing all of them just to be sure, I ran `sudo npm install`.

I also changed the name servers in my domain.

Comment: Are you using a proxy on your server to redirect traffic to your node app?

Comment: have your node server is running ? make sure your node server is configure and running

Answer (score 1):

In Digital Ocean,

Initially we buy a droplet. Later we have to choose the operating system to be installed, in your case you have chosen Linux maybe Ubuntu.

First, set your **ssh access** and configure ssh if needed

Later we have to update the package manager by using `sudo apt-get update`

Copy the NodeJs app into your droplet.

Set up the NodeJs by installing its dependencies and configuring the database etc.

Configure **Nginx** for the your NodeJs app and also add **SSL certificate** if any to the nginx.

**Restart** Nginx after configuring it.

**Run** your NodeJs app.

You should be able to access your NodeJs app if the Nginx is configured correctly.

Hope this helps.